# "Cannot launch conpty" but Command prompt is setup as default profile

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems that my org forbids using many things. Trying to launch python script in VSC returns error

> The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred
> during launch (Cannot launch conpty).

Searching for an answer I found solution in this [issue](http://phoenix2.yizimg.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126678) where someone says to change to using cmd, alternatively to use just profile. So I switched to command prompt as default profile and

> "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"

added in settings.json but same error still returned as I try to launch python script.

What should I change to freely use python in VSCode?
I can use cmd.exe from my user but without admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue my solution was to allow `\\?\C:\Windows\System32\conpty.exe` through software restriction policies with the unrestricted level.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was

```
\\?\C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe
```

You can find out the location that's causing the issue by opening Event Viewer (search via the windows key) and expanding the "Warnings" section in the "Summary of Administrative Events" section.

Double click the one that starts "SoftwareRestric..." in the below:
[image]

Then see at the bottom of this, where it identifies the location:
[image]

You'll need to add this to your Local Security Policy > Software Restriction Policies > Additional Rules

[image]